# How to disable auto space insertion when completing a keyword in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, code-completion

When completing a Java keyword such as `new` and `public`, it automatically adds a space after the keyword. How to disable this specific behavior?

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried looking under Editor->Code Style->Java or EditorConfig?

Comment: I tried turning off smart indent and Live templates all doesn't work.

Comment: Could you please clarify why do you need this?

Comment: @y.bedrov It's a habbit from using other editors which do not do that, so I have tendency to insert space myself. Right now my source files are full of extra spaces.

Comment: You could run "Reformat" to remove extar spaces. Also feel free to create feature request to disable space adding on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA